# binding to the right constructor at runtime - Java

Tags: java, reflection

I came up with a solution today involving creating classes at runtime, after parsing a file, using the [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) API in Java.

```
    while ((line = textReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("([^:]+):([^:]+)::([\\d]+)::([^:]+)::(.+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find())
        {
            String id = m.group(1);
            String className = m.group(2);
            int orderOfExecution = Integer.valueOf(m.group(3));
            String methodNameOrNew = m.group(4);
            Object[] arguments = m.group(5).split("::");
            if (methodNameOrNew.compareTo("new") == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Loading class: " + className);
                if (className.contains("Competition"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (className.contains("$"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Class<?> cl = Class.forName(className);
                    printMembers(cl.getConstructors(), "Constructor");
                    Constructor<?>[] cons = cl.getConstructors();
                    Object obj = cons[0].newInstance(arguments);
                    this.map.put(id, obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and `printMembers()`:

```
private static void printMembers(Member[] mbrs, String s)
{
    out.format("%s:%n", s);
    for (Member mbr : mbrs)
    {
        if (mbr instanceof Field)
            out.format("  %s%n", ((Field) mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Constructor)
            out.format("  %s%n", ((Constructor) mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Method)
            out.format("  %s%n", ((Method) mbr).toGenericString());
    }
    if (mbrs.length == 0)
        out.format("  -- No %s --%n", s);
    out.format("%n");
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Loading class: org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification
Constructor:
  public org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification(org.powertac.common.Broker,org.powertac.common.enumerations.PowerType)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at Parser.parse(Parser.java:64)
    at Parser.main(Parser.java:137)
```

`arguments[]` is : `1 : CONSUMPTION`. How could I create the right constructor, and give it the right arguments (types) ?
For example, in the sample parser I'm using I have:

```
2233:org.powertac.common.Tariff::6::new::6
```

then I have to create a `class` of the type `org.powertac.common.Tariff` (`new` tells me a new object needs to be created, and it takes a `double rate` as argument, in this case `6`. However, I don't know it takes a `double`, only the argument is `String` (`6`). How could I create / convert / cast to the correct type and then assign it to the constructor? My first thought was to create a symbol table, but I'm wondering about an easier solution...

Comment: Just for my curiosity, what are to trying to solve in general? And why to not use standard Java serialization mechanisms (Serialization API, persist to xml/json, etc)

Comment: @mudalov Could you give me more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Class.getConstructor(Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) to choose the constructor that is appropriate for arguments you wish to pass in to `Constructor.newInstance(Object...)`

In your example I'm going to assume an array of `1 : CONSUMPTION` means you have an array equivalent to

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1), "CONSUMPTION"};
```

So you call the following

```
Class clazz = ... //Whatever class reference you have
Constructor c = clazz.getConstructor(Integer.class, String.class);
Object obj = c.newInstance(arguments);
```

If you don't know the types of your arguments you will have to test the argument set against the Class array returned by `Constructor.getParameterTypes()` for each constructor returned by `Class.getConstructors()` until you find a constructor that matches your argument array. More specifically, the array of arguments and array of classes are the same length and each class in the class array passes `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)` for the class of the value in the same position in the argument array.

Implementation of above in code

```
    public boolean canConstruct(Object[] args, Constructor<?> c){
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = c.getParameterTypes(); 
        if(args.length != paramTypes.length){
            return false;
        }

        int i = 0;
        for(Object arg: args){
            if(!paramTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(arg.getClass())){
                return false;
            }
                    i++;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

In order to use this you will have to have your argument array as you want to pass it to the constructor. You could try to edit your input so that it includes type information (this is similar to how java serialization works) so that you can construct the arguments for the constructor argument array via reflection with their own type constructors

Comment: could you give me more details?

Comment: @philippe I added some more detail to the answer.

Comment: If the values you pass in to `Constructor.newInstance(Object...)` are not assignable to the classes represented by the Class array returned by `Constructor.getParameterTypes()` with the correct number of arguments in the correct order, then you will see the argument type mismatch exception as above in your question.

Comment: But if I don't know the type of each of the arguments which the constructor taking, how could I determine / create then at running time?

Comment: I've edited my question, so now it's easier to understand what I'm looking for...

Comment: @philippe Edited the answer again. As mentioned at the bottom of my answer you will probably have to include type information in your input so you can instantiate the arguments for your constructor correctly.